# Is there any simple way to style people's conversation?

Tags: css

Sometimes we may have such content in our web page:

```
A: How's everything going on?
B: Fine, thank you!
```

When the sentence is longer, it will be like:

```
A: How's everything going on? I haven't heard from you for a
long time. I missed you so much.
B: Fine, thank you!
```

But the desired style is:

```
A: How's everything going on? I haven't heard from you for a
   long time. I missed you so much.
B: Fine, thank you!
```

Is it possible to do this with:

1. do not use a `<pre>` tag.
2. can fit any width.

Comment: There are plenty of ways doing that. Pop into [chat] and see how it's done for yourself.

Comment: Look for a site with something similar to what you desire, and view source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plenty of ways to do that, my preferred way is using a definition list like so:

```
<dl>
    <dt>How's everything going on? I haven't heard from you for a
        long time. I missed you so much.</dt>
    <dd>Fine, thank you!</dd>
    <dt>How's everything going on? I haven't heard from you for a
        long time. I missed you so much.</dt>
    <dd>Fine, thank you!</dd>
    <dt>How's everything going on? I haven't heard from you for a
        long time. I missed you so much.</dt>
    <dd>Fine, thank you!</dd>

</dl>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5v62t3n/

Answer (score 1):

So many ways :)

```css
.parent{
  width: 200px;
  display:flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.parent>div{
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    A:
  </div>
  <div>
    How's everything going on? I haven't heard from you for a long time. I missed you so much.
  </div>
</div>
```